# Restful Routes in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I was using Laravel 5.2
and this how I was writing the `named routes`

```
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'admin' ], function () {
Route::resource( 'about', 'AboutController', [ 'as' => 'about' ] );
} );
```

and then this is how I call the route `about.admin.about.update`
Now in Laravel 5.4 it's the same routes

```
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'admin' ], function () {
Route::resource( 'about', 'AboutController', [ 'as' => 'about' ] );
} );
```

but when I call it `about.admin.about.update` it gives route is not defined.
another thing as I understood in `named routes` I can call the routes just like that `about.admin.create`

**Update**
Looking at the command `route:list`

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/about                                          | about.about.index                                 | App\Http\Controllers\AboutController@index                                    | web                      |
|        | POST      | admin/about                                          | about.about.store                                 | App\Http\Controllers\AboutController@store                                    | web                      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/about/create                                   | about.about.create                                | App\Http\Controllers\AboutController@create                                   | web                      |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/about/{about}                                  | about.about.update                                | App\Http\Controllers\AboutController@update                                   | web                      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/about/{about}                                  | about.about.show                                  | App\Http\Controllers\AboutController@show                                     | web                      |
|        | DELETE    | admin/about/{about}                                  | about.about.destroy                               | App\Http\Controllers\AboutController@destroy                                  | web                      |
```

Why the name is `about.about.create` Shouldn't be `about.create`??

any clarification around this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are prefixing the resource route `about` with another `about` when you specify the "as" parameter. Leaving that off should give you what you need:

```
Route::resource('about', 'AboutController');
```

This would give you the routes `about.*`. If you want to have `admin.about.*` add the "as" parameter to the group (don't forget to include the trailing period in the "as" parameter):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::resource('about', 'AboutController');
});
```